# MATLAB Engine application tries to load incompatible DLLs from Windows\System32

Tags: windows, matlab, winapi, dll, matlab-deployment

I wrote a [MATLAB Engine](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-matlab-engine.html) application that my colleagues need to use on their own Windows computers with different versions of MATLAB (i.e. the location of their MATLAB installation varies).  In order for the application to find MATLAB libraries, [MATLAB's `bin\win64` directory is *appended* to the PATH manually](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-and-running-engine-applications-on-windows-operating-systems.html).

Some of these MATLAB libraries rely on other DLLs, such as `tbb.dll`, which also ship with MATLAB.  On some computers an incompatible version of this DLL might be present in the `Windows\System32` directory as well, causing the MATLAB application to fail to start (as it tries to load the incompatible version).

**How can I ensure that my MATLAB Engine application only tries to load the correct versions of these DLLs**, found in MATLAB's installation directory, instead of incompatible versions found in `Windows\System32`?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919667/writing-a-matlab-file-from-a-dll-called-by-labview) is probably related.

Comment: Is it even safe to put MATLAB's directory first on the PATH, before `Windows\System32`?  And would it work?  The problem is that I can't test directly on my colleague's machine and they claimed that it didn't work.

Comment: I'd fix the problem at its root and get rid of these non-system files from system32

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Isn't that likely to break whichever program installed the DLL there?  Is it still common for programs to install DLLs in System32?

Comment: It has never been acceptable to install DLLs in system32. Whichever program put tbb.dll there can presumably be fixed by moving it to the app directory. Given that multiple variants of that DLL exist, anything that puts it in the system directory basically craps all over any other application on the computer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not very familiar with recent versions of Windows.  Does [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mean that when browsing with Windows Explorer that DLL might not actually show up in `C:\Windows\System32`?  Or can I forget about this redirector completely?  Just want to make sure what to tell my colleagues.

Comment: Indeed. If the DLL is 32 bit then it will be in SysWOW64, the 32 bit system directory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I guess by "never" you mean "not for at least three Windows versions".  Prior to Vista and SxS, Microsoft's own example was to put application DLLs in C:\Windows\System(32)

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you have any other suggestions for dealing with the problem than removing the offending DLL from `Windows\System32`?  It happens to be that many of my users also have [LabVIEW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabVIEW) installed which seems to always put DLLs in Windows\System32 for whatever reason ...

Comment: @Szabolcs: Nope.  Intel caused this problem by releasing multiple incompatible DLLs with the exact same filename, and not providing any guidance (that I could find) that these DLLs much be stored in the app directory, never in a system directory where they break apps that require a different build of Threading Building Blocks.  Although past experience with LabVIEW suggests that National Instruments would have done the wrong thing even if Intel had provided clear instructions.

Comment: Have you tried putting the right tbb.dll in your application's directory?  Since the version varies, you might not be able to ship the "right" tbb, but instead copy it from MATLAB path during install of your engine-based app.